# What user info shall I ask for on iOS app signup?

Tags: ios, addressbook

I want users to see friends from their Contact Book who have already joined the app.

Whatsapp asks for phone number on signup but is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Because they need a unique primary ID, most apps/web services use emailID but phone numbers too could be used. Whatsapp uses phone numbers for such.

If you can tell more about what you are trying to do I can give a better answer.

Comment: My app will use email ID but what else do I need to request from the user if I want them to see their friends (from Address book) who are already on the app? For example, do I need to request to send their Address Book info to our server?